# No theme found for specified theme id liferay

Tags: jboss, liferay, liferay-6

I have been deploying a custom theme recently with no problems. However on a recent deploy Liferay reverted to the default classic theme and i had these errors in the log:

It doesn't unregister or register...

```
11:10:20,722 INFO [ServerService Thread Pool -- 254][PluginPackageUtil:1049] Reading plugin package for new-theme
11:10:20,731 INFO [ServerService Thread Pool -- 254][ThemeHotDeployListener:129] Unregistering themes for new-theme
11:10:20,732 INFO [ServerService Thread Pool -- 254][ThemeHotDeployListener:164] 0 themes for new-theme was unregistered
11:10:21,081 INFO [ServerService Thread Pool -- 273][HotDeployImpl:185] Deploying new-theme from queue
11:10:21,082 INFO [ServerService Thread Pool -- 273][PluginPackageUtil:1049] Reading plugin package for new-theme
11:10:21,148 INFO [ServerService Thread Pool -- 273][ThemeHotDeployListener:89] Registering themes for new-theme
11:10:21,232 INFO [ServerService Thread Pool -- 273][ThemeHotDeployListener:107] 0 themes for new-theme are available for use
```

There is nothing else related to the theme deployment in the logs as to why it hasn't been deployed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your theme did not deployed correctly. This might happen if you have changed the database after deploying the theme. please check if your theme is deployed properly, it is present in your web-apps folder. 
and you are referring to same database.

Comment: I haven't changed the database. I've tried removing it from the web-apps folder and re-deploying it with no luck. How do i see the theme in the database?

Comment: Try to redeploy by deleting temp and work folder. Also check the file liferay-look-and-feel.xml. check the tag <theme id="newTheme" name="new-theme" />

Comment: The look and feel file gets generated when it's built. I have checked and the id is the same as before. JBOSS is not registering or unregistering the theme.